# Is there a UTF-8 replacement for BASH?

Tags: bash, utf-8

I often need to write simple BASH scripts on my computer for manipulating files. BASH seems to have difficulty working with UTF-8 content.

- Are there any versions of BASH which are fully UTF-8 compatible?
- Is there a replacement for BASH, which uses a similar or identical syntax, but is UTF-8 compatible?

Comment: Perhaps if you were more specific about what problems you're having, someone might be able to give you an intelligent answer.

Comment: Bash works just fine with UTF-8 (and any other encoding encoding), although arbitrary [binary data can be a hassle](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/058). You might want to check out some [locale documentation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/locale).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take your problem is the usual sed/awk/grep... etc doesn't support unicode, so stackoverflow solutions usually don't work for you?

bash itself is very limited without external programs.

To do what you want, you probably have to code in a more functional programming language other than bash.
UTF-8 itself is not very suitable for processing, you need to parse it into 2-byte or 4 byte character and then process the characters. (i.e. conversion to UTF-16 or UTF-32) and then convert it back to UTF-8 for storage.

Answer (score 3):

Bash itself shouldn't have any problems using UTF8. Most likely your problems are caused by another program, e.g. the terminal emulator or editor. Make sure that your environment is set up to use UTF8. For more information on this, see for example [here](http://fruit.je/utf-8).